# How do I allow Opera to access my intranet without warning from Webdriver tests?

Tags: facebook, webdriver, opera, trusted-sites, remotewebdriver

I'm writing some selenium webdriver tests for a Facebook application. I'm running the tests in a Selenium Grid, and I'm seeing a problem when running in Opera (12.15). When the web app is launched in Facebook (or directly), Opera shows a page:

> A page on the public internet requests data from your private intranet. For security reasons, automatic access is blocked, but you may choose to continue.

I have the option then to continue, or to always continue without being asked again. This works fine while I'm manually using the browser. But Selenium launches a new instance of the browser each time, so the preference needs to be selected again each time.

Is there a way to suppress this warning while the tests are running? A command line option? A DesiredCapability?

This seems like an issue that other people will have run into, but I can't find much, if anything, online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`opera:config` shows the option "Allow Cross Network Navigation", which is what you want. The permalink for it seems to link to `opera:config#Network|AllowCrossNetworkNavigation`, hence we want the preference in section `Network`, key `AllowCrossNetworkNavigation` and as it's displayed as a boolean preference it will take values `0` and `1`.

The next issue is setting it programmatically: OperaDriver has a `public OperaScopePreferences preferences()` letting you do this (see [OperaScopePreferences](http://operasoftware.github.io/operadriver/docs/com/opera/core/systems/preferences/OperaScopePreferences.html) JavaDoc).

So, in short:

```
OperaDriver drv;
OperaScopePreferences prefs = drv.preferences();
prefs.set("Network", "AllowCrossNetworkNavigation", "1");
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to do it slightly differently, maybe because I'm using a RemoteWebDriver. But thanks for putting me on the right track. Here's my solution: 'OperaProfile profile = new OperaProfile();
profile.preferences().set("Network", "Allow Cross Network Navigation", "1");   desiredCapabilities.setCapability("opera.profile", profile);'

Answer (score 0):

This does not work in Opera 33.0.
opera:config has been replaced with opera://flags

After search for an hour, I've come to believe this setting no longer exists
in any form within settings:
opera:config#Network|AllowCrossNetworkNavigation

The closest I could find was:
allow-insecure-localhost 
But that did not allow our project running on local host to allow-cross-network-navigation.

Also did some searches on "cross-network protection" no luck.

I'd say the correct solution for 2015 is to use firefox or chrome.